# How to compute $\int_C (X|dx)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

I have the vector field $X(x,y,z) = (\frac {-y}{x^2+y^2+z^2}, \frac{x}{x^2+y^2+z^2},0)$ on $\mathbb{R} ^3$ \ $\left\{ (0,0,0) \right\}$. I need to compute $\int_C (X|dx)$ over a closed circle of radius $1$ being parallel to the $xy$-plane “at height” $z_0$.

I guess because $z=0$ one can represent that as:

$$\int_C (X|dx)=\int_C\big(\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2+z_0^2}\big)dx+\big(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2+z_0^2}\big)dy$$

where $C:=\{(x,y)|x+y^2=1\}$

Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, all fine with the transformation. This only works because the circle is also orthogonal to the $z$-axis. Regarding the choice of the circle: It _does_ matter where the center of the circle is, so that's not okay.

Comment: @AlexR Can you hint me for which $z_0$ is this integral maximal?

Comment: Look at the denominators. Each of them have a $z_0^2$. What is your thought?

Comment: I guess $z_0^2$.

Comment: I guess you have to _________ $z_0^2$, so the integral is maximal for $z_0 =\ ?$.